# Is removing alcohol to create low/non alcoholic wine/beer feasible for the home brewer?

Tags: brewing, alcohol-content, low-abv

Low/non alcohol beverages are probably more popular than ever before with most major brands and many craft brewers now selling products in this category.

I know there are ways to make low-ABV beverages quite easily, but what about reducing the alcohol after fermentation? Is this something that a typical home-brewer could achieve or does it require techniques and equipment that are realistically not feasible?

Comment: This week on Brülosophy: https://brulosophy.com/2021/11/11/the-brewing-of-non-alcoholic-and-ultralow-alcohol-beer-methods-made-simple/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you would do that other than heating or boiling the liquid but this is going to substantially change the overall character of the beverage.

[Data](https://oasas.ny.gov/news/alcohol-and-cooking) suggests heating an alcoholic beverage to a certain temperature, and holding it there for a given amount of time, reduces the ABV considerably. It does not entirely remove it however. So, this will get you close but not completely "NA".

It's possible a chemical or enzymatic process exists but again, the beverage will most likely not be the same afterwards.

If you like "hoppy" beverages, Lagunitas makes a super tasty "hop water" which is NA. It's quite good considering it's only fizzy water and hops. Otherwise, a low ABV clone kit is going to be your next best option :)

**UPDATE**: For anyone interested, I was at the grocery store today and ran across the [Lagunitas IPNA](https://lagunitas.com/beer/ipna/). ABV comes in under .5%.